# Encoding issue when saving files with javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, file, razor

i've been trying all day to setup a function that creates a file from plaintext or a stream in a razor page. i create csv plaintext in a backend and send it to a frontend where i can save it to a file.

most of the things i have tried have worked perfectly so far, i can save what i get from my backend. but when i look at the file, the character 'ø' has been replaced with "Ã¸".
i have tried specifying utf-8 format and encoded it as html or base64 and plaintext and nothing seems to work.

```
function saveFile(name, type, data) {
   var a = $("<a style='display: none;'/>");
   var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], { type: type }));
   a.attr("href", url);
   a.attr("download", name);
   $("body").append(a);
   a[0].click();
   window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
   a.remove();
}
```

is the way my code currently looks. any ideas?
thank you

Comment: where is the actually code that saves the file ?

Comment: You mean you download a file via this weird a-tag construct and when you save the downloaded file, presumably via the browsers save file dialog, the saved file looks wrong?

Comment: The most common way to save a file seems to be to create an html element with an href then perform a click on the element and delete it so that's what I did.

Answer (score 0):

It actually worked perfectly, I later realized excel was trying to read it with american text which doesn't contain æ ø å. opening it with notepad showed what i was expecting